# How to test deeplinks from a Unity game on an Android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, deep-linking

I've implemented a Unity game (intended to be run on mobile) with [this asset package](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/cross-platform-native-plugins-essential-kit-mobile-ios-android-140111) to help me with mobile native functionality like push notifications and deeplinking (which I'm having trouble with).

The game needs to have basic scheme deeplinking (eg. `petgame://quests`) to help us perform basic functionality when a user clicks a link in an email we send them. I've set up the asset package settings for deeplinks to look like this:

[image: Deeplink settings]

When testing on iOS, I'm able to successfully open up the game when I type the deeplink into my safari. However, I'm having issues testing on Android because when I try to type the deeplink into the browser, it searches Google instead of opening the app up. I've also tried sending the deeplink as a text and trying to click on the link but the phone says it is unable to open the link up.

After looking online on how to test deeplinks on Android and it seems I need to have it running on ADB which doesn't seem possible when building and running from Unity.

Is there a way I can test my deeplinks on Android devices that I build and run from Unity?

Answer (score 0):

it may help you:
in Assets/Plugins (if u dont have the plugins folder create it) add a new file called AndroidManifest.xml, and copy past this inside;

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
<manifest xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
  <application >
    <activity android:name = "com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:theme = "@style/UnityThemeSelector" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="MainLink"/>
      </intent-filter >
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

#here the MainLink is your link call it how ever you want, it's the equivalent of the ios url schemes that we have in the player settings. hope it's usefull